# update cell entries based on a list of X and Y coordinates?

Tags: r

Say that I have a 10 x 5 matrix of zeros in matrix m

```
m <- matrix(0,10,5)
```

which looks like this

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

now I have a list of coordinates in a matrix called xy:

```
     x y
[1,] 3 1
[2,] 7 3
[3,] 8 1
[4,] 9 4
```

and I want to update the matrix by taking each row of coordinates above and adding 1 to the cell in matrix m that it refers to -- so the output would then look like this

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you provide the coordinates as a matrix, 1st column specifiying row, 2nd column specifiying column, you can do:

```
xy = cbind(c(3,7,8,9),c(1,3,1,4))
m[xy] = 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    1    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
```